# How to deploy MoinMoin Wiki server on Heroku platform?

Tags: heroku, moinmoin

I'm using Python 2.7 and MoinMoin 1.9.9, I've deployed the Application on Heroku Platform but I'm facing an issue i.e "Application Error".

You can find my application logs below:

```
2018-05-03T05:39:02.716120+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-05-03 05:39:02,715 INFO MoinMoin.log:152 using logging configuration read from built-in fallback in MoinMoin.log module

2018-05-03T05:39:02.716466+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-05-03 05:39:02,716 INFO MoinMoin.log:158 Running MoinMoin 1.9.9 release code from /app/MoinMoin

2018-05-03T05:39:03.011560+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-05-03 05:39:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

2018-05-03T05:39:03.011523+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-05-03 05:39:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2018-05-03T05:39:03.148289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2018-05-03T05:39:03.090670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3

2018-05-03T09:41:43.560985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-citadel-35464.herokuapp.com request_id=d3919c33-4aea-42fb-922f-dfc5b8ca339e fwd="183.82.120.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-05-03T09:41:45.013289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sheltered-citadel-35464.herokuapp.com request_id=325305d9-9828-4233-ba3a-6196ecf37aab fwd="183.82.120.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-05-03T10:10:28.836690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-citadel-35464.herokuapp.com request_id=d0be2e2f-25ef-45d4-9303-9e4e27fd1cb6 fwd="183.82.120.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-05-03T10:10:29.958878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sheltered-citadel-35464.herokuapp.com request_id=7b2bc98b-c757-4323-8089-986f00c1a11a fwd="183.82.120.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...

2018-05-03T05:39:02.716120+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-05-03 05:39:02,715 INFO MoinMoin.log:152 using logging configuration read from built-in fallback in MoinMoin.log module

2018-05-03T05:39:02.716466+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-05-03 05:39:02,716 INFO MoinMoin.log:158 Running MoinMoin 1.9.9 release code from /app/MoinMoin

2018-05-03T05:39:03.011560+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-05-03 05:39:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

2018-05-03T05:39:03.011523+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-05-03 05:39:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2018-05-03T05:39:03.148289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2018-05-03T05:39:03.090670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3

2018-05-03T09:41:43.560985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-citadel-35464.herokuapp.com request_id=d3919c33-4aea-42fb-922f-dfc5b8ca339e fwd="183.82.120.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-05-03T09:41:45.013289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sheltered-citadel-35464.herokuapp.com request_id=325305d9-9828-4233-ba3a-6196ecf37aab fwd="183.82.120.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-05-03T10:10:28.836690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheltered-citadel-35464.herokuapp.com request_id=d0be2e2f-25ef-45d4-9303-9e4e27fd1cb6 fwd="183.82.120.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-05-03T10:10:29.958878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sheltered-citadel-35464.herokuapp.com request_id=7b2bc98b-c757-4323-8089-986f00c1a11a fwd="183.82.120.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Would you paste your logs here in text format, please, by editing the question? Images are not the best way to share textual data, since they are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines. A formatting tool is available.

Comment: Hi halfer, I've edited my logs please check it now.